# Is there a way to read .npy header without loading the whole file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have many large .npy files and I would like to read their headers without loading the file into memory. I am asking this because I only need the header information, but loading the whole file is slowing down the computation.

Comment: The documentation [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) seems promising -- especially the `read_array_header_x_0(fp)` part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`numpy.lib.format`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) is the relevant module, but it's not terribly well documented how to use it, and IMO there should be an easier to use built-in function for this.  But you can do it.

First you need to determine the format version of the file, then use use either `read_array_header_1_0` or `read_array_header_2_0`.  You can also use the internal function `_read_array_header` which despite being internal is actually easier to use.  Here I've implemented a version-agnostic `read_array_header`:

```
import numpy.lib.format

def read_array_header(fobj):
    version = numpy.lib.format.read_magic(fobj)
    func_name = 'read_array_header_' + '_'.join(str(v) for v in version)
    func = getattr(numpy.lib.format, func_name)
    return func(fobj)
```

Usage:

```
>>> with open('test.npy', 'rb') as fobj:
...     print(read_array_header(fobj))
...
((10,), False, dtype('int64'))
```

The returns the shape of the array, whether or not it is F-contiguous, and the dtype.

Answer (score 1):

As [user8408080 correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226337/is-there-a-way-to-read-npy-header-without-loading-the-whole-file#comment113572500_64226337), the format is well documented.

A simple peeking function could be:

```
import ast
import struct

def read_npy_meta(fh):
    magic = fh.read(6)
    assert magic == b"\x93NUMPY"
    version = fh.read(2)
    header_size, = struct.unpack("<h", fh.read(2))
    header = fh.read(header_size)
    return ast.literal_eval(header.decode("utf-8"))
```

#### Usage:

```
>>> with open("my_npy_file.npy", "rb") as f:
...     meta = read_npy_meta(f)
>>> meta
{'descr': '<i2', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (100, 100, 100)}
```